# How can I avoid adding specific inputs in the GET request data on a form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, get-request

I want to achieve on form submission some inputs to disappear from the form data.

I tried disabling the inputs on form submission

```
$(sellForm).on('submit', function() {
     $(sellForm + " input[name=fiat_amount]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     $(sellForm + " select[name=fiat_currency]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

but when I hit browser's back button it's still disabled and the form is unusable till I refresh the page.

Comment: What is the main purpose—are you trying to not send some input values to the server? Or are you (also) trying to disable some inputs in the user interface?

Comment: Add a hidden element before your element with an identical `name=` - then it will POST the hidden element and not your element.   You'll still get them in the submission, but they won't have any value.

Answer (score 1):

One option could be enabling every element when the site loads:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(shellForm).find("input,select").each(function(){
       $( this ).removeAttr('disabled');
   });
});
```

Comment: I'm getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: element.removeAttr is not a function`

Comment: Not working either. It's not removing the disabled attributes.